# Java - fixing a bug in an "add" method that creates a new object

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, hashmap

There is a HashMap called flights and an ArrayList called planes. The method is meant to create a new flight if the user enters the name of a plane that exists in this.planes. The only problem is that, with this method, there is no way to create two flights with the same plane and different arrival/departures. When you create a new Flight object with the same plane as a previous one, it REPLACES that previous one. I'm wondering how I can keep that from happening.

```
public void addFlight(String planeID, String departure, String arrival) {

    Flight newFlight = null;
    for(Plane p : this.planes) {
        if(p.getID().equals(planeID)) {
            newFlight = new Flight(p, departure, arrival);
        }
    }
    flights.put(planeID, newFlight);
}
```

Since the planeID String being entered determines the plane from this.planes that is assigned to the new Flight, I made a loop that runs through the planes ArrayList to check if the name matches. I'm pretty sure this is what's keeping me from being able to make multiple "Flights" that have the same "Plane" but I don't know what else I can change. I tried adding in this additional if statement but it didn't do what I thought it would.

```
else if (this.flights.keySet().contains(p.getID())) {
    newFlight = new Flight(p, departure, arrival); //In case it is a repeated Plane
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need this

```
HashMap<String,List<Flight>>
```

instead of

```
HashMap<String,Flight>
```

This will help you maintain more than one `Flight` instances in the list mapped with the `planeID`

Answer (score 0):

Flights is a HashMap. This is a data structure that stores items in key/value pairs. In your case, planeID is the key.  So when you are inserting a new flight, it will check the map's contents, see the existing Plane ID & insert your new flight in it's place.  It's how the data structure works.

You need to use something more unique as the key.  An object combining the plane ID & some departure details perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

**Create `HashMap` for planes and `ArrayList` of flights in stead.**

Your design will much more be simplified and you'll get the expected behavior.

Adding code would become

```
public void addFlight(String planeID, String departure, String arrival) {
    flights.add(planes.get(planeID), departure, arrival);
}
```

No need to search, check or worry.

Good luck.

**Edit in response to the comment:**

- You are using plane id's as keys to the `HashMap`. So whichever is unique w.r.t. the key, should be placed in the `HashMap`. Which in this case is plane.
- For storing flights, there were two choices

  1. Aggregation: `HashMap<Plane, List<Flight>>` as suggested by Octopus
  2. Association: `List<Flight>` with `Plane` as a member of `Flight` class.

Both choices are easy to use, but in first choice, your plane reference inside flight class is redundant. So I'd go for second choice.

You should choose whichever suits you best.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. For future reference what is the best way to tell which one should be used?